# Delete all Google cookies from a Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, cookies, greasemonkey

I tried a lot of different scripts, but none worked. How do I delete the cookies created by Google, or all cookies of a site?

Answer (score 4):

Best not to use Greasemonkey for this.  It will be cumbersome, might miss cookies set long after the page loads, and can only delete Google cookies while you are actually browsing Google.

Plus, you have to set the script's `// @include` statements to catch all of Google's current and future domains (google.com, accounts.google.com, mail.google.com, google-analytics.com, etc.). And if Google serves ["Secure cookies"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly) those cannot be touched either.

Best to use a tool built for smartly deleting cookies.  I recommend [Selective Cookie Delete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selectivecookiedelete/).
Also, Google, and other sites, track you with far more and worse than cookies.  It's a good idea to run [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) at least once a week.

---

BUT, if you still want to do this with Greasemonkey, here is the code that will delete many cookies for the domain that the script is running on:

**WARNING:**  JavaScript and Greasemonkey cannot even see all the cookies on a page, nor can "secure" (server only) cookies be deleted.).

```
//--- Loop through cookies and delete them.
var cookieList  = document.cookie.split (/;\s*/);

for (var J = cookieList.length - 1;   J >= 0;  --J) {
    var cookieName = cookieList[J].replace (/\s*(\w+)=.+$/, "$1");

    eraseCookie (cookieName);
}
```

Where `eraseCookie()` is:
(Note that this *eraseCookie* gets many more cookies by attempting all possible paths and the most likely sub-domains.)

```
function eraseCookie (cookieName) {
    //--- ONE-TIME INITS:
    //--- Set possible domains. Omits some rare edge cases.?.
    var domain      = document.domain;
    var domain2     = document.domain.replace (/^www\./, "");
    var domain3     = document.domain.replace (/^(\w+\.)+?(\w+\.\w+)$/, "$2");;

    //--- Get possible paths for the current page:
    var pathNodes   = location.pathname.split ("/").map ( function (pathWord) {
        return '/' + pathWord;
    } );
    var cookPaths   = [""].concat (pathNodes.map ( function (pathNode) {
        if (this.pathStr) {
            this.pathStr += pathNode;
        }
        else {
            this.pathStr = "; path=";
            return (this.pathStr + pathNode);
        }
        return (this.pathStr);
    } ) );

    ( eraseCookie = function (cookieName) {
        //--- For each path, attempt to delete the cookie.
        cookPaths.forEach ( function (pathStr) {
            //--- To delete a cookie, set its expiration date to a past value.
            var diagStr     = cookieName + "=" + pathStr + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
            document.cookie = diagStr;

            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + pathStr + "; domain=" + domain  + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + pathStr + "; domain=" + domain2 + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + pathStr + "; domain=" + domain3 + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
        } );
    } ) (cookieName);
}
```